# Decompose complex matrix transformation into a series of simple transformations?

Tags: math, vector, matrix, transform, decomposition

I wonder if it is possible (and if it is then how) to re-present an arbitrary M3 matrix transformation as a sequence of simpler transformations (such as translate, scale, skew, rotate)

In other words: how to calculate MTranslate, MScale, MRotate, MSkew matrices from the MComplex so that the following equation would be true:

MComplex = MTranslate * MScale * MRotate * MSkew (or in an other order)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Singular Value Decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition) (see also [this blog](http://metamerist.blogspot.com/2006/08/linear-algebra-for-graphics-geeks-svd_25.html) and this [PDF](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~djacobs/CMSC426/LinearAlgebraSVD.pdf)). It turns an arbitrary matrix into a composition of 3 matrices: orthogonal + diagonal + orthogonal. The orthogonal matrices are rotation matrices; the diagonal matrix represents skewing along the primary axes = scaling.

The translation throws a monkey wrench into the game, but what you should do is take out the translation part of the matrix so you have a 3x3 matrix, run SVD on that to give you the rotation+skewing, then add the translation part back in. That way you'll have a rotation + scale + rotation + translate composition of 4 matrices. It's probably possible to do this in 3 matrices (rotation + scaling along some set of axes + translation) but I'm not sure exactly how... maybe a QR decomposition (Q = orthogonal = rotation, but I'm not sure if the R is skew-only or has a rotational part.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but the solution will not be unique. Also you should rather put translation at the end (the order of the rest doesn't matter)

For any given square matrix `A` there exists infinitely many matrices `B` and `C` so that `A = B*C`. Choose any invertible matrix `B` (which means that B^-1 exists or det(B) != 0) and now  `C = B^-1*A`.

So for your solution first decompose `MC` into `MT` and `MS*MR*MSk*I`, choosing MT to be some invertible transposition matrix. Then decompose the rest into `MS` and `MR*MSk*I` so that MS is arbitrary scaling matrix. And so on...

Now if at the end of the fun `I` is an identity matrix (with 1 on diagonal, 0 elsewhere) you're good. If it is not, start over, but choose different matrices ;-)

In fact, using the method above symbolically you can create set of equations that will yield you a parametrized formulas for all of these matrices.

How useful these decompositions would be for you, well - that's another story.

If you type this into *Mathematica* or *Maxima* they'll compute this for you in no time.

Comment: You have a good point, except that these matrices have additional bonds (translation is identity matrix with rightmost column containing translation vector, etc.). As far as I can imagine, these four transformations — granted that order is fixed — should yield unambiguous result.